# Why does an access permission conflict occur when assigning values ​to vertex information?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define MAXVEX 100
#define INFINITY 65535
typedef char VertexType;
typedef int EdgeType;
Boolean visited[100];
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0;
 
typedef struct EdgeNode//建立边表
{
    int adjvex;
    EdgeType weight;
    struct EdgeNode* next;
}EdgeNode;
 
typedef struct VertexNode
{
    VertexType data;
    EdgeNode* firstedge;
}VertexNode, AdjList[MAXVEX];
 
typedef struct
{
    AdjList adjList;
    int numVertexes, numEdges;
}GraphAdjList;
 

void CreateALGraph(GraphAdjList* G)
{
    int i, j, k;
    EdgeNode* e;
    printf("输入顶点数和边数：\n");
    scanf_s("%d%d", &G->numVertexes, &G->numEdges);
    getchar();
    printf("请输入顶点信息：");
    for (i = 0; i < G->numVertexes; i++)
    {
        scanf_s("%c", & G->adjList[i].data);
        G->adjList[i].firstedge = NULL;
        getchar();
    }
    for (k = 0; k < G->numEdges; k++)
    {
        printf("输入边（vi,vj）上的顶点序号：\n");
        scanf_s("%d%d", &i, &j);
        e = (EdgeNode*)malloc(sizeof(EdgeNode));
        e->adjvex = j;//邻接序号为j
        e->next = G->adjList[i].firstedge;
        G->adjList[i].firstedge = e;
        free(e);
 
        e = (EdgeNode*)malloc(sizeof(EdgeNode));
        e->adjvex = i;
        e->next = G->adjList[j].firstedge;
        G->adjList[j].firstedge = e;
        free(e);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
 

void DFS(GraphAdjList GL, int i)
{
    EdgeNode* p;//边表
    visited[i] = TRUE;
    printf("%c", GL.adjList[i].data);
    p = GL.adjList[i].firstedge;
    while (p)
    {
        if (!visited[p->adjvex])
            DFS(GL, p->adjvex);
        p = p->next;
    }
}
 
void  DFSTraverse(GraphAdjList G)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < G.numVertexes; i++)
        visited[i] = FALSE;
    for (i = 0; i < G.numVertexes; i++)
        if (!visited[i])
            DFS(G, i);
}
 
int main()
{
    GraphAdjList G;
    CreateALGraph(&G);
    DFSTraverse(G);
    return 0;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uO60q.png)

As you can see, this is a DFS algorithm in a data structure, but I'm having some trouble, after entering the vertex information, the compiler shows an access violation, can you help me solve this problem, thank you very much!

The compiler shows that an access conflict occurred at e->adjvex=j. I don’t know where to change the code. I hope to make my depth-first traversal algorithm run.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre], including an exact copy of input that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Please don't post links to images. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: `... = e;` followed immediately by `free(e);` is a pattern sure to create [dangling pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer).

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
    G->adjList[i].firstedge = e;
    free(e);
```

`firstedge` becomes a dangling pointer because you `free` it.

Comment: Access conflicts can still occur even if free is not used